# Visual Studio Mac ver 8.2 Mono 6.0 Running Native Xamarin Android - The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: android, xamarin, mono

Visual Studio ver 8.2 Mono 6.0 When Running Native Xamarin Android Error The "InstallPackageAssemblies" task failed  Offset must be within plus or minus 14 hours.

[image]

Anybody that can run from scratch native android from the new version of visual studio mac?

Let me know if you can run or what to do? Thanks

try download and run a hello world using xamarin native android.
https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/

Comment: it works on ver 8.2.1 Mono6..0.311,maybe you could try to reinstall

Comment: Uninstalling and installing Visual Studio doesn't work too. Mono 6.0.311+ has error on timezone GMT+8 changing your mac timezone will solve the issue. Hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and installing Visual Studio doesn't work too. Mono 6.0.311+ has error on timezone GMT+8 changing your mac timezone will solve the issue. Hope it can help someone.